# How can I create a child class which only inherits the methods but not the properties of the parent?

Tags: php, inheritance, properties, parent-child

Suppose I have this code:

First I created the Parent

```
 class Country {
  public $country;
  public $populationcountry;
  public $language;
```

with some methods(which are not relevant for this question)

```
public function function1() {   }
public function function2() {    }
             .
             .
                }  //end of parent class
```

Then I create the child

```
 Class city extends Country 
{
public $populationcity;
}
```

Then I create the objects (fot this example I only created one)

```
$city1 = new city();

$city1->populationcity = 10000;
```

and an array of the objects

```
$cities = [$city1];
```

And finally I want to 'echo' only the child's properties (populationcity)

```
foreach ($cities as $city) {
foreach ($city as $k => $v) {
$city->populationcity;
echo $k . ': ' . $v . '<br>';
 }
}
```

***Output***:
populationcity:10000
country:
populationcountry:
language:

I want to keep the methods of the parent, but not the properties of the parent. How can I achieve that?

---

David in the comments told me to set the properties to Private. I did so, and it worked fine but when I created a Country object , it prints the parent's property in the child class.

This is the code, which gives me this output when the parent properties are Public.

populationcity: 10000
country:
populationcountry:
language:
country: England
populationcountry: 30000
language: English

It should print:

populationcity: 10000
country: England
populationcountry: 30000
language: English

When I set them to Private I get this:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Country::$language in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios.php:141 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios.php on line 141

And when I set them to Protected I get this:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Country::$language in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios.php:141 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios.php on line 141

```
class Country {
  public $country;
  public $populationcountry;
  public $language;
  }

Class city extends Country 
{
public $populationcity;
}

$country1 = new Country();
$country1->language = 'English';
$country1->country = 'ENgland';
$country1->populationcountry = 30000;
$countries = [$country1];

$city1 = new city();
$city1->populationcity = 10000;

$cities = [$city1];

foreach ($cities as $city) {
 foreach ($city as $k => $v) {
$city->populationcity;
echo $k . ': ' . $v . '<br>';
}
}

foreach ($countries as $country) {
foreach ($country as $k => $v) {
$country->language;
$country->populationcountry;
$country->country; 
echo $k . ': ' . $v . '<br>';

}
```

}

Comment: Just make the properties private.

Comment: Hey David. Thanks! It worked for this example. But then, I added a small complexity and it's not working as expected. Where can I show you the code? It's too long for this comment. Shall I edit the post or post an answer? Thanks

Comment: Yeah just edit your question.

Comment: I just did! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bad design pattern. For me a country can contain several different cities. Therefore a city is not a country. Shouldn 't your country entity class look like this?

```
class Country
{
    /**
     * Collection of City objects
     * @var ArrayObject
     */
    protected $cities;
    protected $name;
    protected $population;
    protected $language;

    public function setCity(City $city) : self
    {
        if ($this->cities == null) {
            $this->cities = new ArrayObject();
        }

        $this->cities->append($city);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCities() : ArrayObject
    {
        if ($this->cities == null) {
            $this->cities = new ArrayObject();
        }

        return $this->cities;
    }
}
```

Anyway ... let us solve your issue with php's own reflection classes. To get the properties of the declaring class only just implement the following function in the city class.

```
class City extends Country
{
    public $populationCity;

    public function getData() : array
    {
        $data = [];
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $properties = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            if ($property->getDeclaringClass() == $reflection) {
                $data[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($this);
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

With this you can get the properties of the `City` class only. Let us have a try ...

```
$city = new City();
$city->populationCity = 10000;

var_dump($city->getData());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Marcel! I may need some time to get a grasp of the Reflection function. I edited my question and added more details. Hopefully there's a simpler way to solve it. (And yes, it's a bad design, I'm just using it as an example, I didn't give it much thought, just wanted to build an example where I need to inherit only the methods but not the property)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php) to achieve this.

> Reflection API that adds the ability to reverse-engineer classes,
>   interfaces, functions, methods and extensions. Additionally, the
>   reflection API offers ways to retrieve doc comments for functions,
>   classes and methods.

This will allow you to enumerate the properties and see if any given one is defined in the class itself or along its inheritance chain.

```
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    /* You can move this logic out of the loop and cache the properties 
       if your array contains only elements of the same type */
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($city);
    $class = $reflector->getName(); // Get the name of the current class

    $ownProperties = array_map(function ($e) { return $e->name; },  // Return only the name of 
    // the property
        array_filter($reflector->getProperties(), // Return properties defined in 
        // the same class only, regardless the visibility, since protected properties can
        // either be declared or inherited
             // Check if declaring class is the same as this type
            function($e) use ($class) { return $class === $e->class; } ));
      /* **** */
    foreach ($ownProperties as $property) {
        echo $property . ': ' . $city->$property . '<br>';
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/hv4AR)